# Reemplazar una Lista con un Arreglo

Tags: c#, array, lista

mi consulta es la siguiente Tengo el siguiente método el cual muestro a continuación :

```
public static string loadLista(string pStrOp)
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WXYZ"].ConnectionString);
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("select distinct RTRIM(LTRIM(c.str_val)) as Id , RTRIM(LTRIM(c.str_val)) as Value " +
                                                                                "from dbo.toc a " +
                                                                                "inner join dbo.propval c on c.tocid = a.tocid and c.PROP_ID = 698 " +
                                                                                "where a.pset_id = 114 and c.str_val is not null " +
                                                                                "order by 2 asc;", conn);


    var items = new List<Parametro>();


    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {

                 int fc = dr.FieldCount;
                 var colums = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                 for (int i = 0; i < fc; i++)
                   colums.Add(i, dr.GetName(i));

                object[] values = new object[fc];

                while (dr.Read())
                {

                dr.GetValues(values); //Get All Values
                Parametro item = Activator.CreateInstance<Parametro>();
                var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();

                foreach (var p in props)
                {
                    foreach (var col in colums)
                    {
                        if (p.Name != col.Value) continue;
                        var value = values[col.Key];
                        if (value.GetType() != typeof(DBNull))
                        {
                            p.SetValue(item, value, null);
                        }   
                    }

                }

                items.Add(item);

                }

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("");
    }

    return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(items);
}
```

Como pueden ver hago uso de un SqlCommand para realizar una consulta , luego almaceno esta en un DataReader para procesar los datos y al final guardarlos en una Lista . El método funciona perfectamente, mi consulta es como puedo reemplazar el uso de Listas en este método por Arreglos ya que tengo una limitación la cual me impide usar Listas. Gracias de antemano por la ayuda brindada.

Comment: Podrías describir mejor tu limitación ¿qué te impide usar items.ToArray() ?

Comment: el método forma parte de un proyecto ya implementado el cual no reconoce Listas (Genera un error al usarlas)lo mas probable es que sea por falta de algún assembly. Si se agregara el assembly podría tener algún impacto en otros aspectos , entonces lo que en primera instancia se ha planteado es reemplazar las listas por arreglos

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es calcular primero la cantidad de registros que devuelve tu consulta, crear un array para almacenar esos registros, y luego con el data reader hacer lo mismo que haces, salvo que debes mantener un índice y en lugar de hacer  items.Add(item); al final hacer un  items[i] = item; (tu lista será ahora un array)

Comment: Ojo, que en este último caso, debes asegurarte que la cantidad de registros calculada sea la misma que la devuelta, o por lo menos menor, si los datos cambian entre cálculo y obtención de datos,vas a tener problemas.